# Opening tab using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How can i open `Order` tab using java-script function and also assign active class to the opened tab.

I have tried the below code but it didn't work.

```
<script>
    function showmodal() {
        $('#Order').modal('toggle').addClass('active');

    }
</script>
```

-

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Active Customer</a></li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="showmodal()" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Order</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            home
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="Order">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Order


                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually open a tab by calling `...tab("show")` on the tab's `a` element but since you don't seem to have an `a` element for the `Order` tab, you'll have to add the `active` class to this tab yourself and remove it from the others.

Eg:

```
$("#Order").closest(".tab-content").find(".tab-pane").removeClass("active"); 
$("#Order").addClass("active");
```

You should take a look at the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) to see how to properly use tabs.

Comment: Hello but still the order tab is not opening see the link https://jsfiddle.net/zxtoe1cm/

Comment: @Ayman If you take a look at the console you'll see that there is an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: showmodal is not defined`